# Flask: How to properly use create_app/factory function

Tags: python, shell, authentication, flask

I am trying to make a Flask app for authentication. I am getting this error when trying to start a Python shell session with `flask shell`:
"Detected factory 'create_app' in module 'app', but could not call it without arguments. Use 'app:create_app(args)' to specify arguments."

My directory looks like this:[project directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bT0ZO.png)

My create_app factory function is defined in app/**init**.py as below:

```
def create_app(config_name):
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_object(config[config_name])
    config[config_name].init_app(app)

    bootstrap.init_app(app)
    mail.init_app(app)
    moment.init_app(app)
    db.init_app(app)
    login_manager.init_app(app)
    
    from .main import main as main_blueprint
    with app.app_context():
        app.register_blueprint(main_blueprint)

    from .auth import auth as auth_blueprint
    with app.app_context():
        app.register_blueprint(auth_blueprint, url_prefix='/auth')

    return app
```

, and it's instantiated in flasky.py as follows:

```
`from app import create_app
app = create_app(os.getenv('FLASK_CONFIG') or 'default')`
```

I tried the command `flask --app 'flasky:create_app(default)' shell`, but the error stays. I also tried `app = create_app('default')` in flasky.py with no improvements